# vb.net: detecting which folder desktop is in

Tags: vb.net

usually the desktop folder is something like:

C:\Users\username\Desktop\

is it possible to detect where the desktop folder is using vb.net?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite simple:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)
```